# using an rc522 rfid with a pico w and arduino ide. OR. What is the best way to convert pico sdk programs to use with arduino ide?

Tags: arduino-ide, raspberry-pi-pico, mfrc522

I am trying to setup a lock on a robot project. The pico w i'm using I have already programed it using Arduino IDE, it powers a relay to start an RPi4. What I am looking for is arduino code for the RC522 rfid and pico w. I will incorparate that into my sketch so that if the rfid card is not presented then the relay can not be activated. If needed I can possibly use pico sdk code, if I knew how to convert the .c and .h modules to use with Arduino IDE, is that even possible?